# Select Before The Date

Tags: php, sql, mysql, date

I have a date, say its called $date. I want a a mysql_query to search a select number of weeks,days or even months before my $date. Is this possible? My explanation is not the greatest, but I do need a answer for this and do not know how to properly question it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use mysql interval function?

```
"select * from table where `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(".$date.",INTERVAL 15 DAY ) AND CURDATE( )
```

That'll return the records from the last 15 days, you could use = insted of between if you want the records exactly 15 days old, or modify it for days, months, etc.

edit: if your working with php's time() remeber to use `FROM_UNIXTIME($phpdate)` inside your query.

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution  for this in SQL, Take it, if it would helps you

Day($date) gives you the date in the vaariable
Month($date) gives you the Month in the vaariable
Year($date) gives you the year in the vaariable

using simple where conditions, now you can search for a particulars

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_SUB` functions to modify a date, and mysql understands a BETWEEN clause using dates. However, you can also use the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function like so:

```
"SELECT foo FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, dateField, '$date') < '$desired_days'"
```

Comment: I do not understand, does $desired_days work as just days like "1" or do you mean like "01-01-2011"

Comment: Plus, I dont think my date is formatted correctly. The date I used is the date from gathered from $GET and converted to $date which contains "19-01-2011"

Comment: $desired_days would be a number of days back, not a date. You can use the date formatting methods other people have suggested to fix that issue.